# Failed to enumerate production trees

Tags: opencv, openni

I'm trying the OpenNI sample "openni_capture.cpp"

Before I've done this tutorial
http://seevisionc.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/compiling-opencv-with-openni-for.html

but because I'm working with qt I don't know if i did something wrong, I suppose it's because of Cmake.txt

When I tried the sample I got:
CvCapture_OpenNI::CvCapture_OpenNI : Failed to enumerate production trees: Can't create any node of the reauested type! 
../openni_capture quit with code 255

Can you help me? Thank you!